# jquery page load to get another page content, mouseover how to load once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few pages, like a1.html, a2.html, a3.html, a4.html, a5.html....
All pages HTML Markup looks like

`<div class="wrap">
    <header>Header 2</header>
    <saection>Section 2</section>
    <footer>
        <div class="hover"></div>
    </footer>
</div>`

so when onhover a1.html `.hover` class, then page loads a2.html `.wrap` and appendTo a1.html's body, on the same page, now we have a2.html's contents. when on hover a2.html 's '.hover' (still on a1.html) then loads a3.html's contents and so forth

```
$('.hover').on('mouseover', function(){
   $.get( "/a2.html", function( data ){   
 ///a2.html should be a variable

   $('section', data).appendTo('body');
  });
});
```

My question is how to just load a2.html, a3.html or a4.html contents just once when onhover `.hover` class. How do I test if a2.html is already loaded then, do not load it again? Thanks

Comment: Why not just remove the `.hover` class?

Comment: try to use this function http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_one.asp    and thi http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that.

```
$('.hover').on('mouseover', function(){
    if (!$(this).data('active')) {
        $(this).data('active', true);
        $.get( "/a2.html", function( data ){   
        ///a2.html should be a variable
            $('section', data).appendTo('body');
        });
    }
});
```

Using the data-set to store a flag (`active` here), let you the possibility to remove it later and to process again the handler instructions.

If you really want to load it once (and never ever later), replace `on` by `one` in your code (as told by @SSS).

```
$('.hover').one('mouseover', function(){
   $.get( "/a2.html", function( data ){   
 ///a2.html should be a variable

   $('section', data).appendTo('body');
  });
});
```

---

Be careful : the way you are using `on` (or `one`) binds the `mouseover` event only on **existing** DOM elements.

If you want to affect all **existing and future** DOM elements. You got to use it this way :

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.hover', function(){
    /// your instructions
});
```

Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is $(..).one(event, handler). But what if you really need to do something after loading once and only once in an a asynchronized and promised way?

I have implemented a cards ui application facing the same problem: card defined in another html file which must be loaded and only once before update/show its content. My resolution is based on jQuery Promises API and a simple cache. Wish helpful and here is part of my code (the real one is much more complicated):

```
function expect(proc) {
    var cache = {};
    return function(key) {
        if (!cache[key]) {
            cache[key] = $.Deferred(function(deferred) {proc(deferred, key); })
                          .promise();
        }
        return cache[key];
    };
}

var cards = expect(function(deferred, url) {
    var $loader = $('div');
    function whenDone() {
        deferred.resolve(loader.contents());
    }
    $loader.load(url).then(whenDone);
});

cards('MyCard.html').done(function(contents) {
    // It is promised that MyCard is loaded, do what you want here
});
```